# (Relay) What is the correct syntax to re-run a query based on the result of that query

Tags: graphql, relayjs

Lets say I have a query that gets an `advisors`. That query returns a list of advisor `id`s that are connected to that advisor.  Now I want to rerun the query that got the advisor in the first place, with the `n` number of `id`s, and get those advisors.  I only need to do this once, and not recursively.

```
const query = graphql`
  query AdvisorProfileQuery($id: ID!) {
    advisor: node(id: $id) {
      ... on Advisor {
        name
        assignments (first: 100) {
          edges {
            node {
              id <---- i want these ids and plug them back into the query to just get "name" of the list of ids
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const QueryRenderer = LoadingQueryRenderer(AdvisorProfile, query);
export default ({ i18n }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <QueryRenderer params={{ id: id }} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to create a fragment and splat it in...

Parent component

```
const query = graphql`
  query AdvisorProfileQuery($id: ID!) {
    advisor: node(id: $id) {
      ... on Advisor {
        ... BottomCardTable_advisor
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;

const QueryRenderer = LoadingQueryRenderer(AdvisorProfile, query);
export default ({ i18n }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <QueryRenderer params={{ id: id }} />
    </>
  );
};
```

on child component

```
export default createFragmentContainer(TableComponent, graphql`
  fragment BottomCardTable_advisor on Advisor {
    assignments: assignments (first: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          primaryName
          primaryEmail
          assignedOn
          type
        }
      }
    }
  }
`);
```